# How to correctly format strings like 'mccdougal' to 'McDougal'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

What Ruby or Rails DSL will format a string `"mccdougal"` to `"McDougal"`, and at the same time leave the string `"McDougal"` as is?

Passing `titleize` to `"McDougal"` results in the following:

```
"McDougal".titleize # => "Mc Dougal"
```

Comment: The correct thing to do is to make the user responsible for formatting his or her name, and then not mangling it.

Answer (score 5):

There isn't a Rails helper to my knowledge that can handle this case.  It's a non-standard edge case which needs special handling.  You could create a custom string inflection, however.  You could drop this bit of code in an initializer:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.human /mcdougal/, 'McDougal'
end
```

And then when you call `"mcdougal".humanize`, you'll get `"McDougal"`

Comment: See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector/Inflections.html for more documentation on how this works

Comment: The only problem with this is adding every single "Mc" name in the universe to it, but it does work in this specific case.

Comment: True.   I wonder if something like `inflect.human /mc(.*)/, "Mc #{$1}.titleize" might miraculously work.

Comment: Doesn't look like [`inflections`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector/Inflections.html) takes a `lambda` but it probably should for cases like this.

Answer (score 4):

You aren't going to find something that correctly formats a name like that.  The reason is because the reason that the M and D in McDougal are capitalized is an arbitrary regional thing.  The only way that I can think of doing something like that is with a lookup table.  I would say that the best you'll get programatically is `"mcdougal".capitalize` => "Mcdougal".  I would argue that you can't and shouldn't guess regional capitalizations.

If However you are making an app for the Irish however, and it absolutely needs to be done. I would make a lookup table to solve the problem. It's tedious, but you'll find a finite amount of cases.

Comment: I was halfway typing the almost same answer, u beat me :).